# Getting error while assigning value to a variable in Unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Trying to assign value to a variable as follows

```
n=2
i='hello'
A$n='$i'
```

But getting error as "A2=hello: command not found

My aim is to assign 'hello' to A2 variable(by substituting $n as 2 in A$n)

Comment: With regards to your last line: single quoting will stop interpolation, meaning that `A$n` will be set to `$i` not the value of `i`.

Comment: After removing single quotes also getting same error. Tried like this A$n=$i

Comment: `A$n='$i'` simply is not a valid assignment statement, syntactically. Assignments are recognized by the parser *before* any parameter expansion occurs, and the portion before the `=` must be a valid identifier, which `A$n` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `declare` to achive this:

```
n=2
i='hello'
# as glenn mentioned it's safer to quote the declaration
# because the variables could possibly contain spaces 
declare "A$n=$i"
```

Comment: Safer to write `declare "A$n=$i"`, particularly if the values aren't known.